# How to estimate standard deviation in images with speckle noise?

Tags: python, math, image-processing, statistics, noise

I am using this function that I found on the web, to add speckle noise to images for research purposes:

```py
def add_speckle(k,theta,img):
  
  gauss = np.random.gamma(k, theta, img.size)
  gauss = gauss.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]).astype('uint8')
  noise = img + img * gauss 
  return noise
```

My issue is that I want to estimate/define the speckle noise I add as a standard deviation(sigma) parameter, and this function that I found depends on the gamma distribution or random.gamma() which it depends on the k,theta(shape,scale) parameters, which you can see in the gamma pdf equation down below:

[image]

according to my knowledge, the variance can be calculated in gamma distribution as follows:

[image]

so standard deviation or sigma is equivalent to:

[image]

I want to add speckle noise as sigma dependent, so am saying there should be a way to estimate that sigma from k,theta(shape,scale) that we make the input with, so the speckle_adding() function would look like something like this:

```
def add_speckle(sigma,img):
```

**edited : for the answer in the comments :**

```
def add_speckle(sigma,mean,img):

  theta = sigma ** 2 / mean
  k = mean / theta
  gauss = np.random.gamma(k,theta,img.size)
  gauss = gauss.reshape(img.shape[0],img.shape[1],img.shape[2]).astype('uint8')
  noise = img + img * gauss 
  print("k=",k)
  print("theta=",theta)
  return noise
  img = cv2.imread('/content/Hand.jpeg')
cv2.imwrite('speckle12.jpg',add_speckle(8,3,img))
```

thanks sir for your help, but i really understand why k,theta values changes each time i change values of mean while sigma is constant, i think it must not changes??

Comment: A gamma distribution has two parameters. Knowing sigma isn't enough to fix either one of them, so you need to *make some additional choice* about the distribution you want, *besides* its standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed that `sigma = k ** 0.5 * theta`, there are infinite possibilities for parameters in the gamma distribution if only sigma is given (eg. if sigma is 1, `(k, theta)` can be `(1,1)` or `(4, 0.5)` and so on).

If you really want to generate the speckle with statistical inferences as input, I suggest you to add `mean` as the second input so that the required `(k, theta)` can be calculated.

The first moment (ie. mean) of a gamma distribution is simply `k * theta`.

Example:

```
def add_speckle(mean, sigma, img):
    # find theta
    theta = sigma ** 2 / mean
    k = mean / theta
    
    # your code proceeds...
```

Comment: thanks sir, i tried it, but each time i change the "mean" value, the k,theta values changes that's happened while sigma is constant , i will put the code i tried as an edit

Comment: yes, that makes perfect sense. `theta = sigma ** 2 / mean` so when you change the mean, `theta` and `k` would change accordingly.

Comment: ok thanks sir, i will mark your answer as solved because your solution is the best one